# To raise/lower the blinds or to draw the blinds?

Tags: meaning, verbs, confusables

I'm an English learner and I'd like to know which verb should I use when using the word venetian blinds. Do you say 'to **raise/lower** the blinds' or 'to **pull** the blinds **up/down**?' or 'to **draw** the blinds'? + What would you say if you just wanted to **turn** the slats - would you say something like '**Close/open** the blinds, please.'? It would be really helpful for me if you took the time to answer. :)

Comment: *Raise/lower* or *draw*.  Generally *draw* is applied to curtains, where the meaning is usually to *close* the curtains, but it may also be used with "blinds", where the meaning must be inferred from the context.  *Pull* is also used, but rarer.  (Since all these terms are used, and they are quite dependent on local dialect, family traditions, etc, it's not worth getting your shorts in a knot worrying about which to use.)

Comment: related: [What do you call this sound in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263672/what-do-you-call-this-sound-in-english) The question is about the sound blinds make when someone raises/opens them.

Comment: Mari-Lou's link also gets into the verb a little bit -- you'll want to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

"Raise/lower" would be correct. Instead of "pull", one tends to hear "put" instead. i.e. "put the blinds up", "put the blinds down".

Being British, I've only ever heard "draw" used when the curtains/blinds move sideways from the sides of the window to the middle, not with blinds that go up and down.

As for just turning the slats of Venetian blinds, that's tricky. I think if the blind was already down, but with the slats open, saying "close the blinds" or "close the slats" would be understood correctly, but maybe not if the blinds were up to start with.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of **draw** is to pull (think of draft horses), so whichever way you are drawing curtains or blinds, open, closed, left, right, up, down, it is an acceptable usage.  If you want to be more specific, you certainly can use a different verb (raise, lower, open, close, etc.)

Comment: I agree with Matt and Steven, and would add that 'draw' is intrinsically ambiguous.  Better to say "open/close the curtains/drapes/blinds" and "raise/lower the blinds" [when the slats are actually going up or down].

Answer (score 1):

If the blinds are vertical, use the same verb as you would with [curtains](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/curtain_1): ***draw (open) the blinds***  or ***draw back the blinds***

[image: vertical blinds]

For *roller blinds* (without slats) which you pull on a cord, say: ***roll up /down*** or ***pull up/down the blinds***

[image]

For horizontal blinds with slats ([venetian blinds](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/venetian-blind?q=venetian%20blind)) use the verbs: *open* and *close*  to adjust the amount of light that enters into a room. And *pull up/down the blinds* or *raise* and *lower* to hoist up or down the blinds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Do you say 'to raise/lower the blinds' or 'to pull the blinds up/down?' or 'to draw the blinds'? + What would you say if you just wanted to turn the slats?

To bring them up or down with the cord:

**Raise / lower the blinds**

Note, *pull the blinds* would to me mean to raise them, i.e. let more light in.

To turn the slats to allow more light in:

**Adjust the blinds to let in a little more light**

To turn the slats to block light out:

**Close the blinds.**

Bonus tip:

**Draw the curtain**

means *close the curtain*.  As someone already noted, this is a sideways movement.

Answer (score -2):

Merriam-Webster defines the noun "blind" as a "window shutter," a "roller window shade" or a "Venetian blind," also as "a place of concealment, especially, a concealing enclosure from which one may shoot game or observe wildlife," and as "something put forward for the purpose of misleading," i.e., "subterfuge." There are many different literal denotations and figurative connotations for the word "blind" and its plural form "blinds." With Winston Weathers' "Grammar B" (see Tom Romano) or even poetic license, you can do whatever you want with a blind or blinds.

Merriam-Webster also defines the phrase "draw the blinds/curtain/shades on" as an idiom which means to end something that has been continuing for a long time.

Idiomatic or figurative (metaphorical) language has many different "shades" of meaning, and it changes over time. It evolves as poets and those who create street slang break the rules of grammar. With PREscriptive grammar, language has rules that come from the the top-down, teacher-to-student. With PROscriptive grammar, language evolves from the bottom-up as the rules are broken.

Psycholinguistically, the brain fills in the blanks, reads between the lines and determines what the speaker or writer means, and intuitively gains understanding. Psycholinguistics is the field of study that researches the mental processes making it possible for humans to use, master and understand language. Psycholinguistic research investigates speech and language development and how individuals produce and comprehend language. Most intelligent, insightful people will understand what you mean.

Comment: Although this provides general information, it doesn't answer this specific question.

Comment: Hi jimm101, I've added additional information from Merriam-Webster about the figurative, idiomatic, metaphorical phrase "draw the blinds/curtain/shades on" (yes, Merriam-Webster, which is THE authority on American English, uses the words "draw" and "blinds" in the same sentence, therefore, "draw the blinds" is perfectly acceptable English usage). The information I've provided from primary sources is QUITE specific, and it DOES answer the specific question. I repeat, most INTELLIGENT speakers of English will understand what is meant, even when spoken by ESL (English as a 2nd language) speakers.

Comment: Since this string began more than six years ago, in response, I'll use the following idiom quoted from English language authority Merriam-Webster: perhaps it is time to "draw the blinds on" this conversation...

Comment: Your answer consists of non-essential information. The OP did not ask for a definition or figurative usage of "blinds." As the OP seems to have English as a second language, it is best to be direct and answer with reasons for the contextual use of a particular verb or verbs.